# How to parse nested JSON file in Pandas

Tags: json, pandas

I'm trying to transform a JSON file generated by the Day One Journal to a text file using Python but hit a brick wall.

This is broadly the format:

```
{'metadata': {'version': '1.0'},
 'entries': [{'richText': '{"meta":{"version":1,"small-lines-removed":true,"created":{"platform":"com.bloombuilt.dayone-mac","version":1344}},"contents":[{"attributes":{"line":{"header":1,"identifier":"F78B28DA-488E-489E-9C95-1A0648099792"}},"text":"2022\\n"},{"attributes":{"line":{"header":0,"identifier":"FA8C6594-F43D-4652-B442-DAF72A379799"}},"text":"\\n"},{"attributes":{"line":{"header":0,"identifier":"0923BCC8-B24A-4C0D-963C-73D09561EECD"}},"text":"It’s the beginning of a new year"},{"embeddedObjects":[{"type":"horizontalRuleLine"}]},{"text":"\\n\\n\\n\\n"},{"embeddedObjects":[{"type":"horizontalRuleLine"}]}]}',
   'duration': 0,
   'creationOSVersion': '12.1',
   'weather': {'sunsetDate': '2022-01-12T16:15:28Z',
    'temperatureCelsius': 7,
    'weatherServiceName': 'HAMweather',
    'windBearing': 230,
    'sunriseDate': '2022-01-12T08:00:44Z',
    'conditionsDescription': 'Mostly Clear',
    'pressureMB': 1042,
    'visibilityKM': 48.28020095825195,
    'relativeHumidity': 81,
    'windSpeedKPH': 6,
    'weatherCode': 'clear-night',
    'windChillCelsius': 6.699999809265137},
   'editingTime': 2925.313938140869,
   'timeZone': 'Europe/London',
   'creationDeviceType': 'Hal 9000',
   'uuid': '988D9D9876624FAEB88F9BCC666FD9CD',
   'creationDeviceModel': 'MacBookPro15,2',
   'starred': False,
   'location': {'region': {'center': {'longitude': -0.0095,
      'latitude': 51},
     'radius': 75},
    'localityName': 'London',
    'country': 'United Kingdom',
    'timeZoneName': 'Europe/London',
    'administrativeArea': 'England',
    'longitude': -0.0095,
    'placeName': 'Somewhere',
    'latitude': 51},
   'isPinned': False,
   'creationDevice': 'somedevice'...,
   }
```

I only want the 'text' (of which there might be a number of 'text' entries and 'creationDate' so I've got a daily record.

My code to pull out the data is straightforward:

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('files/2022.json')
     
# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Closing file
f.close()
```

I've tried using list comprensions and then concatenating the Series in Pandas, but two don't match in length - because multiple entries on one day mix up the dataframe.

I wanted to use this code, but:

```
result = []
for i in data['entries']:
    entry = i['creationDate'] + i['text']
    result.append(entry)
```

but I get this error:

KeyError: 'text'

What do I need to do?

Update:

```
{'richText': '{"meta":{"version":1,"small-lines-removed":true,"created":{"platform":"com.bloombuilt.dayone-mac","version":1344}},"contents":[{"text":"Later than I planned\\n"}]}',
   'duration': 0,
   'creationOSVersion': '12.1',
   'weather': {'sunsetDate': '2022-01-12T16:15:28Z',
    'temperatureCelsius': 7,
    'weatherServiceName': 'HAMweather',
    'windBearing': 230,
    'sunriseDate': '2022-01-12T08:00:44Z',
    'conditionsDescription': 'Mostly Clear',
    'pressureMB': 1042,
    'visibilityKM': 48.28020095825195,
    'relativeHumidity': 81,
    'windSpeedKPH': 6,
    'weatherCode': 'clear-night',
    'windChillCelsius': 6.699999809265137},
   'editingTime': 672.3099998235703,
   'timeZone': 'Europe/London',
   'creationDeviceType': 'Computer',
   'uuid': 'F53DCC5E05BB4106A49C76954117DBF4',
   'creationDeviceModel': 'xompurwe',
   'isPinned': False,
   'creationDevice': 'Computer',
   'text': 'Later than I planned \\\n',
   'modifiedDate': '2022-01-05T01:01:29Z',
   'isAllDay': False,
   'creationDate': '2022-01-05T00:39:19Z',
   'creationOSName': 'macOS'},
```

Comment: hi, first of all the json contains few syntax mistakes. However, I can't see creationDate in the json. Please share your desired output of the script.

Comment: I've updated with a more recent json element.

Comment: not sure then what is the issue? entries is missing now... try print(data['text']+data['creationDate']) or please share a good sample so it can be reproduced

Comment: what's the expected outcome? Note that there is no "creationDate" key in here

Comment: It is in the update.

Comment: so what's the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Sort of managed to work a solution - thank you to everyone who helped this morning, particularly @Tomer S.

My solution was:

result = []
for i in data['entries']:
print (i['creationDate'] + i['text'])
result.append(entry)

It still won't get what I want

Comment: Please share the exact result you want to get

Comment: i['creationDate']
i['text']

Comment: please specify an example from the current updated json

Comment: Ideally I want:
2022-01-05T01:01:29Z
Later than I planned